# The specified child already has a parent. Radio Button

Tags: android, radio-button, illegalstateexception, radio-group

I'm trying to do a RadioGroup dynamic from an List Object, I read a lot about the error I have, but the solutions don't help me, I hope you can.

My Structure .xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/green_tataki"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/big_box_user"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <!--SOMETHING-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/identity"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/gentle_view">
                         <!--HERE GOES THE RADIO BUTTON-->
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--SOMETHING-->
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My Activity, filling the radio group:

```
 LinearLayout gentleView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gentle_view);
 final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
 RadioButton rb = new RadioButton[userInfo.getUserSex().size()];
 rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
    for(int i=0; i<userInfo.getUserSex().size()-1; i++)
    {
        rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
        rb[i].setText(userInfo.getUserSex().get(i).getName());
        rb[i].setId(userInfo.getUserSex().get(i).getId());
        ((ViewGroup) gentleView.getParent()).removeView(gentleView);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
    }
    gentleView.addView(rg);
```

As you can see, I put the removeView into for loop. I tried creating the radio group into the xml, and the error is the same:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent.
 You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Really, I don't understand the error well, I tried to solve with other answers, but it doesn't work for me.

========================================EDIT=====================================
My mistake was I'm processing the RadioButton like an Array. So, error disappear, but now, the RadioGroup only show the first item.

Here is the code

```
    for(int i=0; i<userInfo.getUserSex().size()-1; i++)
    {
        rb = new RadioButton(this);
        rb.setText(userInfo.getUserSex().get(i).getName());
        rb.setId(userInfo.getUserSex().get(i).getId());
        rg.addView(rb);
        gentleView.addView(rg);
    }
```

Comment: You are removing gentleView but adding radioButtonGentle[i]. Those are different views. And the error is saying that the View you are trying to add to the ViewGroup is already added to another ViewGroup so you need to remove it from that ViewGroup before trying to add it to another.

Comment: Where is radioButtonGentle defined?

Comment: What view have I to remove? @zgc7009

Comment: Sorry, radioButtonGentle is rb @Egor

Comment: You don't have to remove any Views, you are adding a newly instantiated View to a container ViewGroup. Just add it. Are your id's that you are setting your views to unique?

Comment: when I quit the line with the removeView, still giving me the error :( @zgc7009

Comment: Try adding rg RadiuoGroup to gentleView LinearLayout before you loop to add the array of rb RadiuButtons. Understand though, if you set the id to an id that is taken by another view that already has a parent in the layout you are going to get that error.

Comment: try removing this line((ViewGroup) gentleView.getParent()).removeView(gentleView);

Comment: Ok, @zgc7009 I see my error thank you so much, but, now the RadioGroup only show 1 of my items, I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Now the radioButton, is not an array.

Comment: Are you sure you useInfo.getUserSex() array is larger than 1?

Comment: yes, it has 2 items, it only show me the first one.

Comment: Try setting the orientation to vertical for your RadioGroup. I bet that your view is filling the contents width and the other one is being pushed off the screen.

Comment: it doesn't work, I'm going to edit the article so that you can see how the code is currently. @zgc7009

Comment: Make it `RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);` in your for loop so that you are instantiating a new button every time instead of reinstantiating a single reference to a view each time (for clarity). Also, take `gentleView.addView(rg);` and move it out of the for loop so you don't try to add the RadioGroup every time you add a button, just once once all of the RadioButtons have been added to the group. Lastly, make the loop go through `i < userInfo.getUserSex().size()` removing the minus 1 so you loop through the whole thing. Right now you are stopping short by 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108570/discussion-between-mari-luna-and-zgc7009).